# Imagem online em Adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

Tenho um adapter no meu App, e gostaria de pegar fotos do meu servidor para colocar nele ao invés de uma foto salva na raiz, já tentei varias formas, ja tentei até usando a API Picasso mas o máximo que consegui foi 1 foto para toadas.

Adapter:

```
public CursoAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<curso>  elementos)  {

    super(context,R.layout.linha,  elementos);
    this.context=context;
    this.elementos=  elementos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    Context contexts = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.linha, parent, false);
    TextView nomeCurso = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.nome);
    TextView progresso = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.endereco);
    ImageView imagem = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagem);
    nomeCurso.setText(elementos.get(position).getNome());
    progresso.setText(elementos.get(position).getEndereco());
    imagem.setImageResource(elementos.get(position).getImagem());
    return rowView;
}
```

Minha XML:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagem"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="69dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/e1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="304dp"
    android:layout_height="73dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nome"
        android:layout_width="227dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Nomedascola"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.SearchResult.Title"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endereco"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Endereço"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Adicionando items:

```
 curso e = new curso(array2[0],"Progresso: 0%", drawable.e1);
 escolas.add(e);
 return escolas;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi usando esse esquema: (No meu Adapter)

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        //.makeText(contexts, mag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(Minha_URL).getContent());
        imagem.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```